# headers.append simple syntax

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to append multiple header values. what I am doing is

```
 options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 options.headers.append('X-Requested-By', 'api-client');
 ... etc.,
```

instead of mentioning each one separately, can we do something like

```
ley heads= {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'X-Requested-By': 'api-client',
 ... etc.,
}

options.headers.append(types);
```

or any other methods availabe

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.x/packages/http/test/headers_spec.ts#L51-L56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this as part of RequestOptionsArgs

```
let headers={};
let obj = new Headers(headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this inside the function responsible for the HTTP request service:

```
let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenParse}`);
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders});
```

And then do it:

```
return users = this.http.get<UserList[]>(this.mainUrl, options);
```